# C programming, if statements (large to small integer swap)

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, integer

I have been working on getting code to put 3 numbers in ascending and then descending order. However, the code skips the if statements and assumes that the numbers are in order. This is my first time using if statements in C and my second day of learning pointers so any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swap(int *, int *, int *);
int main(void){

printf("Please enter the first number to sort: ");
scanf("%d",&numberOne);

printf("Please enter the second number to sort: ");
scanf("%d",&numberTwo);

printf("Please enter the third number to sort: ");
scanf("%d",&numberThree);

//swap

swap(&numberOne, &numberTwo, &numberThree);

//return results

printf("The three numbers in descending order is: %d, %d, %d", 
numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree);

printf("THe three numbers in ascending order is: %d, %d, %d", 
numberThree, numberTwo, numberOne);
}

void swap(int *numberOne, int *numberTwo, int *numberThree){
if (numberOne>numberTwo){
if (numberTwo<numberThree){
int temp =*numberTwo;
*numberTwo=*numberThree;
*numberThree = temp; }
// "312"

else if (numberTwo>numberOne){
    if (numberOne>numberThree){
    int temp =*numberOne;
    *numberOne =*numberTwo;
    *numberTwo= temp;
    // "231"
}
    else if(numberOne<numberThree){
    if(numberTwo>numberThree){
    int temp =*numberOne;
    *numberOne =*numberTwo;
    *numberTwo =*numberThree;
    *numberThree = temp;
    // "132"
    }
    }
}
else if (numberThree > numberOne){
    if (numberTwo< numberOne){
    int temp =*numberThree;
    *numberThree =*numberTwo;
    *numberTwo =*numberOne;
    *numberOne = temp;
    // "213"
}
else {
    int temp = *numberThree;
    *numberThree = *numberOne;
    *numberOne = temp;
    // "123"
    }
}

}
else{
printf("Look at that these numbers were in order...");
}
}
```

Comment: Try to ask smart questions. Try to find a minimal code, which still shows your problem. Most of the time you will find the solution yourself in that process.

Comment: I'll suggest:  you make your code easier to debug by making it easier to read.  Indent it appropriately and it'll be much easier.  It's also easier to debug when you make it modular; you need a function that swaps 2 ints, since you're doing this repeatedly.  Try these things and as michas points out, you may be able to fix it yourself -- and becoming someone who writes clear, debuggable code has got to be more important in the long term than solving one particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this: `if (numberTwo>numberOne)`, you are comparing the pointers. And you need to compare the values contained behind those pointers. So do: `if (*numberTwo>*numberOne)`

Comment: mk, i changed it up and it still gives me the same order. i'll keep looking into it

Answer (score 0):

would this work? !!!
BTW! the definition of 'large integer' and 'small integer' has other technical meaning.

```
void swap(int *numberOne, int *numberTwo, int *numberThree){
    int tmp;

    if(*numberOne > *numberThree ){
        tmp             = *numberThree;
        *numberThree    = *numberOne;
        *numberOne    = tmp;
    }


    if(*numberTwo > *numberThree ){
        tmp             = *numberThree;
        *numberThree    = *numberTwo;
        *numberTwo    = tmp;
    }
    if(*numberOne > *numberTwo ){
        tmp             = *numberTwo;
        *numberTwo    = *numberOne;
        *numberOne    = tmp;
    }


}
```